Can't crop black bars in MPC-HC using MadVR
I have my MPC-HC set to use MadVR, and MadVR is set to "automatically detect hard coded black bars" and "crop black bars", but I still can't get the same zoom in behavior (view > video frame > touch window from outside) that I get with a video without black bars. Using MadVR's "always shift the image" option does align the image to top or bottom, so detection clearly works but it's not really cropping them out because I can't zoom in like regular pan & scan? Am I using it wrong or is it not possible? I'm not married to MadVR but I do need something that handles both HDR and black bar cropping.
